# how to find the SVG text location

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Here is my code,

```
<html>
<body>
<svg id="text" height="400" width="400" >
<text transform="rotate(127,128,64)" opacity="1" text-anchor="start" font-weight="regular" font-style="Normal" font-family="Segoe UI" font-size="12px" fill="#191919" y="68.25" x="128" id="caption">Revenue </text>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the text(Revenue) start x location is 128.
how to find the x location of last char(e) of the text(Revenue).
need a genuine calculation. because the rotation of the degree is changeable.

Comment: Call  getStartPositionOfChar

Comment: can't understand how it is possible using that method can u please show the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call getStartPositionOfChar and convert the local co-ordinates by transforming them e.g.

```js
var pos = document.getElementById("text").getStartPositionOfChar(6);
var matrix = document.getElementById("text").transform.animVal.getItem(0).matrix;
var position = pos.matrixTransform(matrix);
alert(position.x + ", " + position.y);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<svg height="400" width="400" >
<text id="text" transform="rotate(127,128,64)" opacity="1" text-anchor="start" font-weight="regular" font-style="Normal" font-family="Segoe UI" font-size="12px" fill="#191919" y="68.25" x="128" id="caption">Revenue </text>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it shows the wrong output.. (167,68.25) how it's correct because The default text location is 128,68.25  when rotate the text in 127 deg the last char of the text x location is need to show less than 128

Comment: The co-ordinates are in the transformed co-ordinate system. I've changed the answer so you can see how to transform them.

Comment: Hai Robert thanks for your help... it's working...one more question.. i need a same output before append the text how?

Comment: If you have another question it's best to ask it separately. You'll need to provide more details though as I don't understand your comment.